# GCSE: Find the surface of a volleyball ball

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

Can anyone help me?!

How many cm$^2$ of skin is needed to make a volleyball ball with a diameter of $30$ cm, if for cutting and sewing $12\%$ of the material is lost? 
My attempt was the following: 
I used the sphere surface formula:
$S=4\pi r^2 = 4(3,14)(225\text{cm}^2) = 2826 \text{cm}^2$ 
So, $\frac{12}{100} \cdot 2826 = 339,12cm$
Then, 2826+339,12 = 3165,12 cm

I don’t know if this is the right answer! All help/solutions appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to take into account the 12 percent loss in materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not quite right, unfortunately. What you have calculated is $12\%$ of the surface area of *the volleyball* and added that on. Unfortunately, you don't lose $12\%$ of the surface area of the *volleyball* by cutting and sewing, you lose $12\%$ of the material you started with. Adding $12\%$ of the latter does not account for a loss of $12\%$ of the former. What you would want to solve is:

$0.88x = 2826$

where $x$ is the original fabric. Can you solve it from here?

Aside from this final step, everything else in your solution looks good.

Comment: I don’t understand where you get the 1.12x, please can explain me how to solve it?

Comment: Apologies, that should have been $0.88$. That is, $(1 - 0.12)$, 12% less than the original surface area would be $88\%$ of the original area. T

Comment: Thank you so much